# How to stop App from entering background before asynchronous task has completed

Tags: ios, dropbox

I'm developing an iOS app which syncs with Dropbox. I use the Dropbox SDK for iOS. I'm facing the problem that the Dropbox sync consists of two asynchronous operations of which only the first is completed when the app resigns the active state.

What would be a good way to prevent the app from resigning active (or terminating) before the asynchronous tasks have completed? Would a blocking call (with sensible timeout) in the applicationWillResignActive: method be an option? If yes, how would that be best implemented?

Thanks in advance for your support!

Cheers,
Georg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that preventing immediate termination of your app goes against the Interface Guidelines. If your app is eligible for backgrounding (GPS, VOIP or Audio playback), then you will be able to do whatever you need in the background. If not, for all I know, you should do whatever you need in the willResignActive: method as a preparation for your app termination. Don't forget that the user may also completely terminate the app and that you need to make sure everything works out fine in that scenario as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer stavash. That would mean that I would have to live with the fact that I don't know at the time the app starts or returns from the background whether or not a network request to push data to Dropbox completed, or not, which probably greatly complicates matters. I wonder how the other apps using Dropbox solve this particular problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to actively check the status of an operation that was previously made? Does the Dropbox API support such a thing? Anyways, I hope you find a solution, it is indeed an interesting problem.